# How to combine one key with array as value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array and I want to create a table with that array as a column in codeigniter.

How can I combine data that as another array?

Here are my column names

```
Array
(
    [0] => System_ID
    [1] => Last Name
    [2] => First Name
    [3] => Full Name
    [4] => Phone
    [5] => Ext
    [6] => Email
    [7] => Dept
    [8] => Site
    [9] => Room
    [10] => Job Title
    [11] => Image
    [12] => URL
    [13] => Active
)
```

And here is the array that I want to combine as value

```
Array
(
    [type] => VARCHAR
    [constraint] => 200
)
```

This is the final result I want:

```
$fields = array(
    'System_ID' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '100',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Where `type`, `constraint` and `users` came from?

Comment: @MickaëlLeger This is just a example, replace user with first array that i define and type and constraint is static value

Comment: Why in second array constraint is 200, but in result - 100?

Comment: is `array_value` supposed to relate to your first array? i have to say this is rather unclear.

Comment: @Alex yes, array value is my first array

Comment: This is very unclear and also a bit of an odd request. Can you provide a more exact input and output?

Comment: @u_mulder i picked this example from codeignter documentation, https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html#CI_DB_forge::create_table

Comment: So given an array of 13 entries and an array of 1 entry you get back an array of 1 entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want same value for all values from first array, then simple [`array_fill_keys`](https://php.net/array_fill_keys) will work:

```
$array1 = ['System ID', 'Last Name'];
$array2 = [
    'type' => 'VARCHAR',
    'constraint' => '200',
];
print_r(array_fill_keys($array1, $array2));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3CPtd).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then this should work. Iterate through the first array and use its value as the index for the new array (names must be unique now) and then add the array `to_add` as the value.

```
$to_add = ['type' => 'VARCHAR', 'constraint' => 100];

$data = [];

foreach ($first_array as $index => $value) {

    $data[$value] = $to_add;

}

print_r($data);
```

I will add, I think it is odd to have all columns with the same characteristics. For example, an ID is usually an `unsigned int 11`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = array_flip($array_with_column_names);

array_walk($result, function(&$value) {
    $value = $array_with_needed_values;
});

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: solution made by `u_mulder` is better)

Comment: yes haha, we should probably just delete our answers but i'll keep it up for posterity ;)